# Writing threads in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, performance

Can we achieve multi-threading in JavaScript?

If yes, please suggest a method to run multiple tasks on multiple threads in JavaScript/Angular.

Thanks

Comment: Javascript is single threaded, the engine is multithreaded (I\O happens on other thread, unless you use sync flag)

if you want to open thread you can use `Web Worker`
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers

Comment: What kind of work-load do you have there? All I/O (like network requests) is asynchronous and multiplexed on that single thread already.

Answer (score 7):

You could use Web worker, a dedicated thread that doesn't block the UI.
They work in a background thread

> Web Workers is a simple means for web content to run scripts in
>   background threads. The worker thread can perform tasks without
>   interfering with the user interface. In addition, they can perform I/O
>   using XMLHttpRequest (although the responseXML and channel attributes
>   are always null). Once created, a worker can send messages to the
>   JavaScript code that created it by posting messages to an event
>   handler specified by that code (and vice versa.) This article provides
>   a detailed introduction to using web workers.

**mainThread.js**

```
if (window.Worker) {
  var myWorker = new Worker('worker.js');

  // Posting data to worker
  myWorker.postMessage('Message posted to worker');

  // Receiving data from worker
  myWorker.onmessage = function(e) {
    console.log('Message received from worker: ' + e.data);
  }
}
```

**worker.js**

```
onmessage = function(e) {
  // Receiving data from main thread
  console.log('Message received from main script: ' + e.data);

  // Posting data to the main thread
  postMessage('Posting message back to main script');
}
```

For further information read the documentation in [MDN Web Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers)

Answer (score 1):

> Using `Web worker` you can achieve multithreading in addition use can
>   use `service-worker` that will acts like your proxy-server, with that you can achive multithreading at network level.

*Things to note about a service worker:*

- It's a [JavaScript Worker](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/workers/basics/), so it can't access the DOM directly.
  Instead, a service worker can communicate with the pages it controls
  by responding to messages sent via the [postMessage](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/workers.html#dom-worker-postmessage) interface,
  and those pages can manipulate the DOM if needed.
- Service worker is a programmable network proxy, allowing you to
  control how network requests from your page are handled.
- It's terminated when not in use, and restarted when it's next needed,
  so you cannot rely on global state within a service worker's
  `onfetch` and `onmessage` handlers. If there is information that you
  need to persist and reuse across restarts, service workers do have
  access to the [IndexedDB API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API).
- Service workers make extensive use of promises, so if you're new to
  promises, then you should stop reading this and check out [Promises,
  an introduction](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/promises).